# Get called classes

Tags: php

I need to get all called classes inside a class with several functions.

Input is something like:

```
<?php
class someClass
{
    function firstFunction()
    {
        $form = new FormClass();
        ...
        ...
    }

    function secondFunction()
    {
        $otherForm = new otherFormClass();
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Excpected output should be something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => FormClass
    [1] => otherFormClass
)
```

Any suggestions how to solve it?

Comment: At what time do you need this information? And why? Not sure what you want to achieve and if you need the information at runtime or in development.

Comment: What exactly are you after? your question isnt clear

Comment: I need to analyze all called classes inside a class to extract them. Afterwards I'm trying to extract the translateable strings from the classes.

The `someClass` isn't called, I'm just getting the content of it with `file_get_contents`. I tried it with `token_get_all` but I doesn't look like it's containing the requested information.

Comment: I've never used it, but something like http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Parser seems to do what you want. It can tell you: "any class names used in any context."

Comment: Can you limit the cases to `$x = new something;`? What about something like `$x = Factory::getInstance(1,2,3);`? Otherwise it is probably quite difficult for static code analysis to find all possible ways to create a new instance _and_ find the corresponding class. Or, are you sure that you can "trigger" all instantiations at runtime? A profiler (and the repsective analyzing tools) can give you some of the information you need. A tool for code coverage may tell you the missing parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform static code analysis you will need a php parser. You can find one at https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser. It's compatible with PHP versions 5.2 to 5.6. The parser breaks the PHP source up into tokens witch you can work with. Since I never used it I'm  not able to provide you with sample sources, but I'm sure the docs at the linked github repo will guide you